# Snowflake's REGEXP_SUBSTR with Python connector

Tags: python, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am building a query with regex using the web UI, something like this:

```sql
SELECT uid, REGEXP_SUBSTR(PAGEPAGEPATHLEVEL3, '/(\\d+).*', 1, 1, 'e') as listing_id, SUM(TOTALHITS) as hits
FROM ga
WHERE PAGEPAGEPATHLEVEL2 = '/sales/'
GROUP BY (uid, listing_id)
```

And it works perfectly. However, once I pass the same query via python/pandas connection

```
pd.read_sql_query(query, con=con)
```

it also works, but all cells in `listing_id` are empty! I assume something In the regex should be escaped, but can't find any documentation on that

Comment: You probably need to use a raw string or double escape the backslashes i.e. `\\\\d`

Comment: Can you share the complete Python code example, including where `query` is initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes in your Python code. Add a `r` before your string:

```py
query = r"""
SELECT uid, REGEXP_SUBSTR(PAGEPAGEPATHLEVEL3, '/(\\d+).*', 1, 1, 'e') as listing_id, SUM(TOTALHITS) as hits
FROM ga
WHERE PAGEPAGEPATHLEVEL2 = '/sales/'
GROUP BY (uid, listing_id)
"""
```

or double the backslashes:

```py
query = """
SELECT uid, REGEXP_SUBSTR(PAGEPAGEPATHLEVEL3, '/(\\\\d+).*', 1, 1, 'e') as listing_id, SUM(TOTALHITS) as hits
FROM ga
WHERE PAGEPAGEPATHLEVEL2 = '/sales/'
GROUP BY (uid, listing_id)
"""
```